# Using hibernate with java console application

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, console-application

Maybe my question is very basic, but regretfully I have very little experience with Java EE applications and little understanding of Hibernate.

I am developing a console Java application (that is not-Java EE application), for which I want to configure Hibernate to do the ORM to MySQL database I use for persistence of my data. However, I don't know how to do that and was never able to find any source in the net about it.

So basically:

- I have downloaded and put in my buildpath `hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-1.0.1.Final.jar`, `hibernate3.jar` and `mysql-connector-java-5.1.19-bin.jar` libraries.
- I know that I need `persistence.xml` file to declare my persistence units. In an ordinary Java EE application this will reside in `src/META-INF/persistence.xml`. However, I am not sure where should I place the file in the case of java console application.
- I was never able to tell whether including the jars in the buildpath and adding the `persistence.xml` is enough to get me going with Hibernate, so please say if something else is needed.

I hope that somebody with more experience with Hibernate can help me get going.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this set of video tutorials: http://embedr.com/playlist/java-hibernate-tutorial

It will help.

Comment: It is finally the time I pay back for this answer. It took me several days to get used to what Hibernate has to offer. I now realize I was far from correct in my statement I have just a little more to configure. Thank you for the great help!

Comment: Link to video tutorial is not available for now.